# Jquery add values from dropdown to text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having trouble trying to accomplishing this.. Whatever option I select from a dropdown list named `programs_dropdown` I want to add to a text field named `programs_input` and separate the options values by a comma.

e.g. `php, jquery, html`

Below the dropdown list I have an `add` div. On click, it should add what I selected from the dropdown to the text field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var programs = $("#programs_dropdown").val(); //get value of selected option
        $('#programs_input').val(programs.join(',')); //add to text input
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="programs_dropdown" id="programs_dropdown">
<option value="php">php</option>
<option value="jquery">jquery</option>
<option value="html" selected="selected">HTML</option>
</select>

<div id=add">Add</div>

<input type="text" name="programs_input" id="programs_input" />
```

I'm getting `skill.join is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select has to multi option if you want to select multiple. Change it to

```
<select name="programs_dropdown" id="programs_dropdown" multiple>
```

Then it would start working.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hs8g6/)

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var program = $("#programs_dropdown").val(); //get value of selected option
        var programs = $('#programs_input').val().split(",");
        if (programs[0] == "") {
            programs.pop()
        }

        if ($.inArray(program, programs) == -1) {
            programs.push(program);
        }

        $('#programs_input').val(programs.join(',')); //add to text input
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hs8g6/1)

Comment: Thanks for the demo but I need it to be a dropdown. I want to add values one by one via `add` div depending what I have selected.

Comment: btw, what does the `-1` in the second statement mean? I am trying to learn the code and can't figure that out.

Comment: It is checking for the presence of program in programs array. Unfortunately the inArray doesn't return bool (as expected) but returns index of the element found and -1 if the element is not found. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you :) The script you provided is brilliant, I also learned a lot by studying it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you require [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ba7Wn/)

Comment: There is a bug in it. Try clicking the Add more than once while the same option is selected.

Comment: Do you want unique items in textbox? If yes, here's the updated [Demo] http://jsfiddle.net/ba7Wn/1/